# Rspec let variable isn't an argument for a Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

In my Test, Rpec, I have this

```
   before { @user = create(:user) }
   let(:mail) { SignUpMailer.message(@user) }
```

Then I get an error of:

```
 Failure/Error: @mail = SignUpMailer.message(@user) }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I have also tried:

```
before { @user = create(:user)
         @mail = SignUpMailer.message(@user) }
```

But it still says the error above. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**
Mailer Code

```
class SignUpMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Assign It App <support@assignitapp.com>"

      # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
      # with the following lookup:
      #
      #   en.sign_up_mailer.message.subject
      #
      def message(user)
        @sign_in_url = sign_in_url
        @user_name = user.name
        mail subject: "Welcome to Assign It App"
        mail to: user.email
      end
    end
```

**Another Work around attempt:**

```
before { @user = create(:user) }
let(:mail) { SignUpMailer.message([@user]) }
```

Which give me

```
 Failure/Error: let(:mail) { SignUpMailer.message([@user]) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for #<Array:0xa0c9860>
```

So the mailer does accept arguments .

Comment: Is your `message` method in `SignUpMailer` accepting a parameter? I would bet it's missing. If not please post that code as well.

Comment: I have posted the Mailer and a attempted work around.

Comment: Wondering where this `create(:user)` method is from. If you are using factory_girl shouldn't it be `@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`?

Comment: This comes from The new FactoryGirl. It is defined in the spec helper.           
  `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods`

Comment: Another guess: Is your `name` method on User requiring a parameter?

Comment: No, `name` is an attribute of the User model, which doesn't exist. I just remove the name call from the Mailer Class and I started to give me the error of no arguments.